# How to export an activity so other apps can call it?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharing

Well I searched a lot, but I didn't find a precise answer how to export an Activity, so an app can start it with `startActivityforResult`.

How do I achieve that? Do I have to change the Manifest in some ways?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to declare an intent-filter in your Manifest (I took the following example from Barcode Scanner) :

```
<activity android:name="...">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then create an intent with the same action string :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
startActivityForResult(intent, code);
```

Android should start your activity (or it will show a drop-down box if there are multiple apps sharing the same action string).

Comment: Thanks, I just read through the Barcodescanner Manifest and found out the same thing. :]

Answer (score 32):

As an alternate to Dalmas' answer, you can actually export an `Activity` without creating an `<intent-filter>` (along with the hassle of coming up with a custom action).

In the `Manifest` edit your `Activity` tag like so:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SomeActivity"
    ....
    android:exported="true" />
```

The important part is **`android:exported="true"`**, this [`export`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported) tag determines "whether or not the activity can be launched by components of other applications". If your `<activity>` contains an `<intent-filter>` then this tag is set to `true` automatically, if it does not then it is set to `false` by default.

Then to launch the `Activity` do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("package name", "fully-qualified name of activity"));
startActivity(i);
```

Of course with this method you will need to know the exact name of the Activity you are trying to launch.

Comment: thanks so much! my app suddenly started throwing this error even after making an inconsequential change, even after I removed that change, but this fixed that!

Comment: very good specification about the default behavior. An external app was saying that the main activity of my app was exported and I couldn't understand why until I read your answer... have a good day!