# Are there any inter-app communication facilities in the Worklight API?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

Are there any specific facilities in [IBM Worklight](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/mobilefirstfoundation) (to be renamed shortly to IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation) for inter-app communication - for example, sending files or data between apps?

[iOS has these facilities natively](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html), [as does Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198444/inter-application-communication-in-android), but I can't find any specific Worklight APIs which refer to or exploit these features. I assume they could be used within a custom Cordova plugin or a Worklight Native API project, but I'm trying to understand if there are any other possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no Worklight APIs available that use those features you mention to share files and data. There is the [Simple Data sharing feature](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_simple_data_sharing_overview.html), but this is meant only for relatively small strings.

Like you said, you can use those directly in a Cordova Plugin or in your native application, based on what you application's needs are.