# How to open SubActivity of an application inside another application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I want to open an subactivity of one application inside another application for that I am doing

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.audiopreferences.SystemAudioSettings"));

    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Inside Android Manifest File:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.android.settings.audiopreferences.SystemAudioSettings"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="SystemAudioSettings">

        </activity>
```

if i execute above Im getting the below Exception

```
id=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fac930)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2741): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2741): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.audiopreferences.SystemAudioSettings } from ProcessRecord{414c0b58 2741:com.dea600.radioapp/u0a10071} (pid=2741, uid=10071) not exported from uid 1000
E/AndroidRuntime
```

Comment: May be it helps you to figure put issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22929102/1897797

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `intent filter` for you activity.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150003/how-to-export-an-activity-so-other-apps-can-call-it) answer.