# Error running second Activity: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter

Tags: android, android-intent

I cant seem to launch my application. It gives me an error like this: "Error running second Activity: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter".

Is there anything wrong with my manifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sg.edu.rp.g913.mymakeuppouch">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".secondActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11551693/3395198

Comment: thanks, got it working already

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Put `android:exported="true"` in the `<activity>` tag

```
<activity android:name=".secondActivity"
    android:exported="true">
```

Answer (score 5):

You should set the Run>edit configuration to the desired launcher activity and give the intent filter at the manifest to the correct activity

below is the error creating situation

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Page_2">
    </activity>
</application>
```

[Image showing incorrect configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB3ll.jpg)

correct configuration and code are given below to run Mainactivity as launcher activity

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Page_2">
        </activity>
    </application>
```

[corrected configuration window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkGPQ.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

1. Get to your Run menu and select edit configuration.
2. In the run/debug configuration widows, select your app in the left column (if it is not yet selected).
3. under launch option: launch, click the side arrow and choose the "specified activity" option.
4. type in the name of the activity you which to launch your apps with or tab on the side button(...) and select from your activities.